# Some questions about the Kitaev Chain Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440),'Unpaired Majorana Fermions in Quantum Wires', Kitaev shows that unpaired Majorana Modes can be found at the end of a Quantum Wire for certain conditions.

1. The effective Hamiltonian between the two modes $b'$ and $b"$ is given to be $H_{eff} = i\frac{t}{2} b'b"$ (equation 15), where $t$ is given to be proportional to $exp(-L/l_0)$. Could anyone nudge me in the direction of arriving at this relation? I think that the overlap between the two modes would be a deciding factor here, and that would be about the order given(hence, the states are robust and not prone to error),but a less handwavy explanation is welcome.

Also, the fact that the ground states would have different energies is in itself weird, because as in the special case(b) in the paper, $-ib'b"$, $b'$ and $b"$ commute with Hamiltonian. So shouldn't the two ground states mediated by $b'$ have the same energy?

2. What exactly is $S(L)$? Is this just a placeholder?

Comment: Regarding (1): you are correct! Both the fermionic operator and the majorana operator will swap between the ground states. This is because both $a^\dagger$ and $c$ anticommute with the parity operator $P$.

Comment: Hi Arnab. Taken together, this question is probably *too broad* (our terminology for things that can't be answered concisely). I would suggest splitting this up into 5 or so separate questions. They can link to each other if need be, but since they can be answered independently it's probably best to ask them independently.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Would it do?